# AngularJS filtering by object prototype function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I would like to filter an ng-repeat using a function defined on the repeat item's prototype, but I can't find any reference saying whether this is actually possible. Something like

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{'isAdmin()': true} | orderBy:'getFullName()'">
    {{user.getFullName()}}
</div>
```

where isAdmin returns a boolean value. orderBy works with this notation, but filter does not seem to work with any notation I try. Is there any way to accomplish this without a separate function that checks isAdmin()?

Answer (score 1):

you could call a function defined in the controller:

```
$scope.isAdmin = function(x) {
    if (x.name == 'bob') {
      return true;  
    }
 }
```

The function must return either true or false.

and use it in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isAdmin | orderBy:'getFullName()'">
    {{user.getFullName()}}
</div>
```

***or*** create a **[custome filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)** , for example:

```
app.filter('isAdmin', [function() {
    return function(users) {
      var filtered = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];

        //here you can use what ever function you want to check if user is admin
        if (user.name == 'bob') {
          filtered.push(user);
        }
      }
      return filtered;
    };
  }
]);
```

and use it in your HTML like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | isAdmin | orderBy:'getFullName()'">
    {{user.getFullName()}}
</div>
```

here's a **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XEZkcmCnuWukuskkrFFy?p=preview)**